# What is wrong with my stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to create a stored procedure using a Dynamic SQL solution because I need to include several nesting if conditions.  I receive the following error when I run the code in Query Analyzeer.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Procedure'.
```

The procedure I am trying to create follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sp_Payments]') 
AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
Drop procedure sp_Payments
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max),
    @categoryID smallint,
    @startDate datetime,
    @stopDate datetime,
    @debtCode tinyint,
    @izEscrow tinyint


Create Procedure sp_Payments
    (@categoryID smallint,
    @startDate datetime,
    @stopDate datetime,
    @debtCode tinyint,
    @izEscrow tinyint
    )
AS
BEGIN
Declare @Payments table( 
        paydate datetime, 
        principaldue float, 
        interestdue float, 
        debtid int, 
        debtname varchar(50), 
        debtnumber varchar(10), 
        fsrc varchar(40), 
        category varchar(40), 
        PayMonth tinyint,
        PayYear int
)
SET @SQL = '
insert into @Payments 
        select dtl.paydate, 
            dtl.principaldue, 
            dtl.interestdue, 
            dtl.debtid, 
            dmf.debtname, 
            dmf.debtnumber, 
            fsrc.fsrc, 
            app.category, 
            month(dtl.paydate) as PayMonth,
            case
                when month(PayDate) <= 6 then year(PayDate)
                else year(PayDate)+1  
            end "PayYear"
             from debtdetail dtl 
            inner join masterfile dmf 
            on dtl.debtid = dmf.debtid
            inner join categories app
            on dmf.categoryid = app.categoryid
            left outer join fsrc 
            on dmf.fsrcid = fsrc.fsrcid
            left outer join debtissues di
            on dmf.issueid = di.issueid
              where dtl.debtid in 
            (select debtid from masterfile
                where categoryid = @categoryID '

        IF @debtCode > 0    
            SET @SQL = @SQL + '
                AND codeid = @debtCode 
                '
            SET @SQL = @SQL + '
                ) 
                AND di.iscontingent = 0 
                '
            IF @stopDate = '' 
                SET @SQL = @SQL + '
                    and dtl.paydate >= @startDate 
                '
            ELSE 
                SET @SQL = @SQL + '
                    and dtl.paydate between  
                    @startDate AND @stopDate
                '
            IF @izEscrow = 0
                SET @SQL = @SQL + '
                    and dtl.isescrow = 0
                '
            SET @SQL = @SQL + '
            and (principaldue + interestdue) > 0 and dtl.active = 1
                    order by dtl.Paydate, dmf.DebtNumber '
EXEC @SQL
END

    SELECT * from @Payments

RETURN




END
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You need `GO`s between your batches here.

Comment: There are other issues as well.  This is a pretty backwards design.  Why do you declare all your variables and then creates params with the same names?

Comment: Query Analyzer? Did you mean Management Studio? If you are running this code against SQL Server 2000, there are many things that will prevent it from working. Please specify the version of SQL Server you are using. [tag:sql-server] is not specific enough.

Comment: JNK, I am not very proficient with my stored procedure fu.  Thanks for your input.  I do know the query works when called as part of a cold fusion component but we wanted to move to stored procedures for optimization.  Aaron, I am using Management Studio Express and my db version is 9.0.5057 which I think is mssql 2000.

Comment: No, 9.0.xxxx is SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Get rid of that dynamic sql, and do something like:

```
AND (@debtCode = 0 OR codeId = @debtCode)
... and so on
```

Comment: Probably not appropriate language for a site for professional developers.